# How to show the checklist filter data when it is clicked on the filter component

Tags: sxa, solr, search-facet

Using Sitecore 9.0.1 with SXA 1.7 and I want to display the checklist filter data when it is clicked on the item. Can anyone please explain how can I do that?
Below are the things which I have done till now:

1. Created a custom fruit template with fields such as Name, Image and Color.
2. Created a facet to filter by Name.
3. Created a rendering variant for the fields.

Below is the result I am getting

[image]

When I click on *apple* the result is just the name of it. I am not getting the image and color of it.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Could it be that you only have the filter component on your page, but not a search result component?

Comment: i have my search result component in another page cant this be redirected to that search result page @gatogordo

Answer (score 0):

You do need to have a search results component on the page where the filters are set.

A search box component has a search page property - this component can be on another page (or your header to have it everywhere) and "redirect" to a search page.

In case of a filter this doesn't make that much sense as they react on the search results. So those components need to be on the same page. It is also a good practice to use the signatures in the component settings to hook them together.

But to solve your issue: move the filters to the search result page where they belong.